# Twitter gem works just in 1 controller. Returns nil otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter

I am using the [Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem for retrieving tweets and displaying them in different places in the platform.
I am using an initializer to make the connection:

`$twitter  = Twitter::REST::Client.new(TWITTER_CREDENTIALS)`

`TWITTER_CREDENTIALS` are defined in the constants file.

In my pages controller I am rending some tweets on the home page like this:

```
def home
  @description = "Hello World"
  @tweets = $twitter.user_timeline(current_region.twitter_handle, count: 4)
  @companies = Company.first(2)
end
```

and it works like a charm. Even if I subsitute `current_region.twitter_handle` with any twitter handle, it renders the tweets on the homepage.

Now here is where the problem starts. In my companies controller, I am trying to do the same, however `@tweets == nil` so my view can't even render. Here is my code from the second controller. It is completely identical, just a different username.

```
def show
  @company = Company.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @tweets = $twitter.user_timeline(@company.twitter, count: 4)
end
```

I can't seem to figure out why it works when called from 1 controller and doesn't from the other. Any ideas ideas on why this might be happening are welcome. For testing purposes, in my `show` view I am doing

```
<div><%= @tweets.inspect %></div>
<div><%= @company.twitter %></div>
```

And those print:

```
nil
"example handle"
```

EDIT:

I opened the rails console and if I run the lines for `show` action, `@tweets` is not nil anymore. It returns the proper object. Maybe that helps to figure out the problem.

Comment: Have you tested whether `Company.find_by_id(params[:id])` really returns something? BTW: `Company.find(params[:id]` is doing the same job.

Comment: Yes, it does return the company object. I am using it 100 more times in the view, so that should't be the problem.

Comment: I searched the gem's source just a bit, but I cannot find the twitter method. Just for explanation: What's the difference between twitter_handle (home action) and twitter (show action)?

Comment: This is an attribute from the model, which I am using to pass the twitter handle as its dynamic. The method is `user_timeline("twitter handle")` In my case, in the `Company` object the twitter handle is within the `twitter` attribute. Its explained here: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why but the only way I could make it work is by loading the `user_timeline` in the actual view. So in my view I have this on top `tweets = $twitter.user_timeline(@company.twitter, count: 4)` and it works fine.

If somebody has an idea why it works in this way and not the other, please go ahead and let us know. I would love to know.